# No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am developing `ear` application, with `gwt web module` and `ejb` module. maven builds succesfully. I inherited `gxt module`. In hosted mode my application doesn't render. In `gwt dev mode` I see following errors:

> [ERROR] Line 62: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.Window; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>   ERROR] Line 71: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.VerticalLayoutContainer; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>   [ERROR] Line 73: No source code is available for type com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.form.FieldSet; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>   ..
>   ..
>
> 00:00:15.285 [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly

here is my `gwt.xml`

```
<module rename-to='xxx'>
 <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>

 <inherits name="com.google.gwt.resources.Resources" />

  <inherits name="com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT" />

  <entry-point class='com.example.XX'/>



   <source path='client'/>
   <source path='shared'/>

 </module>
```

and here is my my `pom.xml` for `gwt web app`

```
<properties>
    <gwtVersion>2.5.1</gwtVersion>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}          </webappDirectory>
</properties>

<build>
    <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-iNF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>

                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <!-- for development mode -->
            <configuration>

                <debugSuspend>false</debugSuspend>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                <runTarget>xxx/xxx.html</runTarget>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
                <noServer>true</noServer>

                <port>8080</port>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </build>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sencha.gxt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gxt</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>    
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

please help me. there is no compilation error during `maven` build

Comment: Have tried to clean the project? maven -> update project? create a new run configuration?

Comment: If it can be compiled to JS but can't be run in dev mode, something is wrong with your dev mode setup. Can you share the full log? Are you sure that the gxt jar (and others) are on the dev mode run config's classpath?

Answer (score 1):

In your [projectname].GWT.xml you also have to add a reference to GXT

```
<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT'/>
```